# Python - check if string contains special characters, if yes, replace them

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a number of strings in the loop, some strings contain "," and some doesn't contain, I want my code to check if there is any "," present in a string remove them and then print the string, and if its not present, print the string as it is.
here is my code:

```
for x in range(y):
c = containers[x].find("div",{"class":"cong-data"})
meeting = c.p.next_element
print(meeting)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Have you tried to research anything? StackOverflow is not your research assistant. Such a question must had been asked before. _waiting for someone to dupehammer_

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Regular Expression [sub() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

```
import re

string = 'aabcdefg,hijklmnop,qrstu,ssads'
remove_commas = re.sub(',', '', string)

print(string)
print(remove_commas)
```

output:

```
aabcdefg,hijklmnop,qrstu,ssads
aabcdefghijklmnopqrstussads
```